# Given number n. Find the n digit numbers.

Tags: algorithms, math-software

For eg; if n = 2,

Then the output should be 10,11,...99 // (i.e) 10 to 99

if n = 3,

Output: 100,101...999 //note the 3 digit numbers are returned. The range would be 100 to 999.

How can i achieve this. Is there any formula to get the range.

Comment: For $n = 2$ shouldn't the range be $10..99$?

Comment: sorry. i have edited my question

Comment: Simply output the numbers from $10^{n-1}$ to $10^n-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range $[a, b] \cap \mathbb N$ of numbers with $n$ digits is determined by
$$\begin{align*}
a &= 10^{n - 1}\\
b &= 10^n - 1.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Great. Thanks..

Comment: @iPhoneGuy Glad to have helped! You can accept the question by clicking the tick mark under the votes buttons. You'll have to wait a bit to be able to accept the question though.